# Rails Geocoder Displaying Users Lat Long to Use for Distance

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, geolocation

I have Geocoder setup and installed and can run functions like

```
  <%= Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([47.858205,2.294359], [@company.latitude,@company.longitude]) %>
```

Which outputs distance to the company. I would like however to use the Geolocation data to be able to replace the "47.858205,2.294359" with their actual cooridnates obtained from their mobile browser.

I am currently using the Google Geolocation Javascript HTML5 to request the users location. http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/source/browse/trunk/js/geo.js?r=74

How can I display this lat and long in my views? I would like it to look something like this

```
   <%= Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([@lat,@long], [@company.latitude,@company.longitude]) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the Geocoder gem to geolocate on the server side.  The Geocoder gem adds a location method to the `request` object available in controller actions.  So in your controller action you could do:

```
@lat = request.location.latitude
@long = request.location.longitude
```

And then use those values in the view code you have there.

Geocoder uses the request's IP address to geolocate.  I'm not sure if this will be less accurate than using geolocation through the browser (which may also use IP address, I don't really know how the implementation works for that).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'm still running on localhost but I'm sure it works on the server, cheers.